# Is there a way to write a unit test in C# to ensure a method isn't called anywhere in a project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

In our application we enforce that all dates stored as strings should be in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.  So, for example if we are storing a date in a Lucene index I want to ensure that it is always stored in the format:

```
2014-03-12T23:03:13Z
```

We have an extension method `DateTime.ToISO8601DateTimeString()` to make this easy along with unit testing around existing code ensuring this is always the case.

I wonder however whether it is possible to ensure `DateTime.ToString()` is never called in code (With the exception of it's overloads)?

Possible routes:

- Reflection
- Pre-commit hooks in SVN
- Override `DateTime.ToString()` with an exception

Has anyone successfully achieved this in the past with a similar method?

### Update

To clarify, I want this to be application wide and automatically fail if new code is added anywhere in a project calling `DateTime.ToString()`

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: You can with Moles: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/

Comment: Why not just design your code so it is not possible to save it any other way? Also, you can't do this because ToString is called implicitly any time you try to access it as string, it is easy to get string's date value without having to explicitly call ToString.

Comment: @Phill we use Moq with NUnit.

Comment: @jgauffin first time I've heard of Moles and it looks promising, I'll do some research.

Comment: You could probably write a rule for StyleCop or Resharper to enforce that (in the obvious case of the compiler knowing it's `DateTime.ToString()`...`object.ToString()` or implied `ToString()`s wouldn't be so detectable).

Comment: @Euphoric I agree with your point, but your statement is inaccurate. There is no implicit conversion from DateTime to string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be OT, but I really think you should not do this.

The correct way to do this is to create `CustomDate` class, that is used in your application instead of `DateTime`. If you ensure the application can't accept `DateTime` and that `CustomDate` uses the conversion you want then there is no need to do any kind of testing.

And note, that this code will not trigger your test, yet will bring problem:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
String str = "now is :"+now;
```

Comment: I concur with this message. After reading the update from the Question. Don't do this! Listen to Euphoric!

Comment: I agree one should not do this without thinking about it but I don't agree one should NEVER do it. After all, precisely the example of the "CustomDate" you're using, you'll want to add a mole so that any call to DateTime.Now produces a failure (controlled) so that you ensure everyone is using CustomDate and not DateTime.Now

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba You don't understand. It should be perfectly fine to use DateTime anywhere except the places where you expect the specific formatting. The places you expect the specific formatting should only accept CustomDate. The need to enforce specific use of class really seems like bad design code smell to me.

Comment: You're right, I though he wanted to disallow completely usage of DateTime, not to disallow ussage of "toString"

Comment: `DateTime.ToString()` to be precise.  I completely agree with @Euphoric in that a `CustomDate` class is exactly what I want moving forward, it doesn't however stop developers from accidentally using `DateTime.ToString()`, which is the issue I'm trying to resolve.  If I can have a test that says "Hang on, shouldn't that actually be using `CustomDate`" then that's a win.

Comment: @Click-Rex The point is to make sure every time you store date, you store it as CustomDate, not as a string. Your problem stems from the fact you store data in non-typesafe way. So it is not easy to ensure specific rules that could be tied to types. You are trying to solve symptom, not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't see the point of a separate date type. The problem is that the save methods are accepting `string` which makes formatting the caller's responsibility. All we need to do is make them accept `DateTime` instead and call `ToISO8601DateTimeString` internally.

Answer (score 4):

Using Moq (most mocking frameworks have this feature).

```
// Method should never be called
mock.Verify(foo => foo.Execute("ping"), Times.Never());
```

If you can't mock your method (because is not an interface) you can try using microsoft fakes (moles) to do the work.

Simply put an assert.Fail inside the Mole so that it will fail the test if called.

**Edit:** As @Euphoric said you should have a good reason to do that. However with that said you can use moles to produce the expected result. Using MS Test Fakes:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
   System.Fakes.ShimDateTime.NowGet = () => Assert.Fail("DateTime.Now called");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge; I've updated my question to clarify this needs to be a project wide check.

Comment: Edited to provided an answer. Notice using moles that way it's valid but if you have a good reason for it (i.e. if you want to make you never call DateTime.Now because you have your own method to do it that uses NodaTime).